# Email links urls depending on device

Tags: ios, email

I need to send emails from iPhone application.

I want some link in email that will be like 'Read post'. This link should open application landing page or app download page if app is not present, and open app if app is present.

1. Is this possible?
2. Can I at least put user-agent condition to email body text to target ios devices?

Currently user always gets to landing.page.com/?redirectTo=inappUrl 
Landing page checks if user agent is ios and tries loading appprotocolurl://inappUrl
This solution though works not very well when app is not installed. Also I would like skip going to landing page and go directly in application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check whether an app is installed through an email, unfortunately.

As a solution you could add two buttons/links; one that says "Read in `your app name`" or "Download app" with the appropriate links/URL scheme to your app.

Answer (score 0):

As runmad pointed out, any if/or logic can not exist in email. You can however link to a webpage what can run that logic for you. This would give you a one button solution with as many options you want being triggered in the webpage load.

Comment: This is what I'm using now and I've written I already do that

Comment: Sorry - glazed over the last part of your question. These are the only two options. You can't be sure they have the app installed, so you either have to have 2 buttons or do it dynamically on the web.